# GraalVM: Error could not find target field: private static during native image build in Quarkus

Tags: java, docker, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

There are pretty big count of questions regarding native images based on GraalVM in Quarkus. Let me add new one.

Basically I have a Quarkus app which uses org.apache.camel to support Amazon SQS functionality. When I start building the native image using OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 21.3.3 I always get the following error

```
Error: could not find target field: private static org.apache.camel.quarkus.support.common.runtime.graal.SubstituteBeansWeakCache org.apache.camel.quarkus.support.common.runtime.graal.SubstituteBeansIntrospector.declaredMethodCache
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: could not find target field: private static org.apache.camel.quarkus.support.common.runtime.graal.SubstituteBeansWeakCache org.apache.camel.quarkus.support.common.runtime.graal.SubstituteBeansIntrospector.declaredMethodCache
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:73)
```

which tells me as it seems to me that GraalVM-engine experiencing some problems when analyzes the SubstituteBeansWeakCache.

In such case quarkus guide [recommends](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips) to use the maven argument like this

```
<quarkus.native.additional-build-args>--initialize-at-run-time=com.example.SomeClass\,org.acme.SomeOtherClass</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
```

but pity it does not work in terms of above-mentioned error keeps happening.

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3645#issuecomment-1692315047 may help, is this same issue ?

Comment: It was me who created the issue

Comment: did you update the camel dependencies and did it fix it ? you can put it as answer :)